# setup varnish on a debian8 with apache2

Tags: debian, apache2, varnish, apache2.4

So i am testing varnish for the first time on a server 
my OS is debian8 and i am using Apache2 
I've installed varnish with apt-get install varnish it did nothing
so i tried to follow some tutorials such as https://www.unixmen.com/install-and-configure-varnish-cache-for-apache-on-debian-7/.
However it did not work
either i get the error for not working with port 80 from curl
or the website goes down.
so ideas?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you have not changed anything after installing varnish (as you said), it will be listening on port 6081, and not 80. Also, check if varnish is running with `/etc/init.d/varnish status`. If it's not, start it with `/etc/init.d/varnish start`.

To put varnish on port 80, check out this: https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/tutorial/putting_varnish_on_port_80.html

Comment: here is another thing that i've tried https://www.unixmen.com/install-and-configure-varnish-cache-for-apache-on-debian-7/ and it did not work